# Media Queries and "display: none" for creating mobile version

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am just asking, since didn't find anything relevant here.

Is using media queries together with `display: none` a legit thing for creating a mobile version of the web-site? I mean, is this an acceptable practice or is there another way to do so?

I just used it on a project, looks alright, but maybe there are some snags here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (what kind of | how much) content are you hiding?

Comment: some blocks that are not essential for the lower resolutions

Comment: blocks containing what? Text? Images? Scripts? If you hide them via CSS are you saving bandwidth?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan filtering modules mostly. It actually doesn't matter what I want to hide. My question was regarding how legit and accaptable it is to create a "mobile version" using ``display: none``

Answer (score 0):

You could only work with media queries instead of having one default css. In that case you wouldn't need to set something that you don't use in other resolutions.

e.g.
put here everything which you don't wanna show in the lower resolutions:
`@media only all and (min-width: 1024)`